# Hapi js - How to send a request for the server to make a basic authentication?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, authorization, backend, hapi.js

I build a nodejs and vuejs web application, 
and I load the vue js dist files from the server, and render them. 
In addition, I am using the hapi-auth-basic. And now I want to make a connection between the server and the front end, but now, it just shows me a prompt window with the basic fields, and I want to embed the authentication proccess in my login form in the vue template. so how can I do it? 
I just want to do the same action that call behind the scence in the prompt window
that appears.

```
await server.register([require('hapi-auth-basic'), require('inert')]);

server.auth.strategy('simple', 'basic', {
            key: privateKey, 
            validate: validate,
            // validate: validate 
        });

server.route({
            method: 'GET',
            path: '/{param*}',
            options: {
                auth: 'simple'
            },
            handler: {
                directory: {
                    path: '.',
                    redirectToSlash: true,
                    index: true,
                }
            }
        });
```

For example, in the above route, the prompt window appears.

Answer (score 1):

```
ROUTES

 {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/api/plumber/getHydrantJSON',
        options: {
            description: 'getHydrantJSON',
            auth :'HYDRA',
            tags: ['api', 'information'],
            handler: async (request, h)=> {
                return Controller.PlumberController.getHydrantJSON(request.query,request.auth.credentials)
                    .then(result =>{
                        return h.response(UniversalFunctions.sendSuccess(Config.APP_CONSTANTS.STATUS_MSG.SUCCESS.LOGIN, result));
                    })
                    .catch(reason =>{
                        return h.response(UniversalFunctions.sendError(reason));
                    })
            },
            validate: {
                query: {
                    skip:Joi.number(),
                    limit:Joi.number()
                },
                headers: UniversalFunctions.authorizationHeaderObj,
                failAction: UniversalFunctions.failActionFunction
            },
            plugins: {
                'hapi-swagger': {
                    payloadType: 'form'
                }
            }
        }
    }



 //authentication

exports.plugin = {
    name: 'auth',
    register: async (server, options) => {
        await server.register(require('hapi-auth-jwt2'));
        server.auth.strategy(
            'HYDRA',
            'jwt',
            {
                key          :  Config.APP_CONSTANTS.SERVER.JWT_SECRET_KEY,          //  Never Share your secret key
                validate     :  TokenManager.verifyToken,                           //   validate function defined above
                verifyOptions: { algorithms: [ 'HS256' ] }                         //    pick a strong algorithm
            });

       // server.auth.default('ADMIN');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters I think you're using the wrong authentication strategy for this kind of application. Instead of **hapi-auth-basic** I'd use [hapi-auth-cookie](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-cookie) or [hapi-auth-jwt2](https://github.com/dwyl/hapi-auth-jwt2).

The strategy you choose will determine how you send your authenticated session to the server. For JWT (JSON Web Tokens) you'd send them as either a Header value on the client or as a cookie - there's a few handy Vue client libraries for handling this that work fairly well - [vue-auth is my favorite](https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth).

For hapi-auth-cookie you wouldn't need to do anything so long as your Vue app is on the same domain as your hapi server - just make sure you pass in `withAuthentication: true` in your axios/$http calls on the Vue client so it knows to send the cookies.